# CSS image overlap positioning

Tags: html, css, image, resize, overlap

What I am specifically looking to do, is have the blue block and red block scale with the webpage, but also remain in place without shifting up and down like they are now.

Here is a gif demonstrating that it does what I want somewhat when scaling diagonally, but scaling either vertically or horizontally results in off positioning.

[Imgur link to demo gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3EAW.jpg)

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="blockDisplay">
    <center><img src="greenBlock.png" class="greenBlock">
    <img src="redBlock.png" class="redBlock">
    <img src="blueBlock.png" class="blueBlock"></center>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.blockDisplay {
      background-color: #444;
      overflow: hidden;
}
.greenBlock {
      position: relative;
      width: 58%;
      z-index: 2;
}
.redBlock {
      position: absolute;
      top: 6%;
      left: 66%;
      width: 8vw;
      z-index: 4;
}
.blueBlock {
      position: absolute;
      top: 40vh;
      left: 77%;
      width: 23vw;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Try giving `position: relative` to the `.blockDisplay` Might not exactly solve your case, but maybe it'll put you in the direction

Comment: Ludovit's suggestion worked flawlessly! It now does exactly what I want it to. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then here it as as an answer

```css
.blockDisplay {
      background-color: #444;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
}
.greenBlock {
      width: 58%;
      z-index: 2;
}
.redBlock {
      position: absolute;
      top: 6%;
      left: 66%;
      width: 8vw;
      z-index: 4;
}
.blueBlock {
      position: absolute;
      top: 40vh;
      left: 77%;
      width: 23vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockDisplay">
  <center>
    <img src="greenBlock.png" class="greenBlock">
    <img src="redBlock.png" class="redBlock">
    <img src="blueBlock.png" class="blueBlock">
  </center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this hope it's helpful for you.

CSS

```css
.blockDisplay {
      background-color: #444;
      overflow: hidden;
}
.greenBlock {
      position: relative;
      width: 58%;
      z-index: 2;
}
.redBlock {
      position: absolute;
      top: 6%;
      left: 66%;
      width: 8vw;
      z-index: 4;
}
.blueBlock {
      position: absolute;
      top: 39vh;
      left: 76%;
      width: 40vw;
      height: 10vw;


}
#divOnTop { z-index: 1000;
```

```html
<div class="blockDisplay">
    <center><img src="greenBlock.png" class="greenBlock">
    <img src="redBlock.png" class="redBlock">
    <img id="divOnTop" src="blueBlock.png" class="blueBlock"></center>
</div>
```

Comment: With positon: relative added to .blockDisplay. The code does exactly what I need it to now